# Ruby on Rails tutorial if (user_id = session[:user_id])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following [ruby on rails](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) tutorial by Michael Hartl and I don't get how he's using assignment operator inside if condintion:

```
if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
end
```

Can someone please explain the logic behind it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the syntactic sugar in Ruby.

Ruby allows you to assign variables in conditionals and returns the value

`x = true #=> returns true`

```
if (user_id = session[:user_id])
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
end
```

is equivalent to

```
user_id = session[:user_id]
if user_id
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
end
```

Saves you a line. 
In case, `session[:user_id]` is falsy, it assigns the false value to `user_id` and doesn't execute the block.

Comment: It's not exactly the same. In the first example user_id's scope is just the body of the if. In the latter user_id is defined after the if as well.

Comment: @Ursus: wrong. Give it a try in irb. `if` is not a scope-gate in Ruby. A new scope is created whenever you define a class, module, or method. Read more about that in Scope Gate section here - http://hopsoft.github.io/blog/ruby-metaprogramming-idioms/

Comment: `x = false; puts 'foo' if (y=x); y #=> false`

Comment: It's important to note that logically true and false in Ruby are quite different from other languages, they're unusually strict. The only logically false values are `nil` and `false`, that's it. 0, an empty string or array, they're all considered *truthful* from a logical perspective.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to use the assignment operator in an `if` statement because an assignment is an expression. The result of the assignment expression is the value of what you are assigning.

In this case, if `session[:user_id]` is not `nil` or `false`, the result of the `if` branch will be called and `user_id` will be set to the result of `session[:user_id]`. If `session[:user_id]` is `nil` or `false` it will still be assigned to `user_id` but the logic inside the `if` will not evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to doing this:

```
user_id = session[:user_id]
if user_id
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what the assignment operator is trying to say... This is saying that if @current_user value is null, then set that equal to user_id. Otherwise, keep the @current_user value. You can read it as `@current_user = @current_user || User.find_by(id: user_id)`